# Could the non-official flavour flag have an automatic comment like duplicate has?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

When you flag a question with a duplicate flag, it automatically sends a comment like

> Does this answer your question? How to run Visual Studio Code as root

But for the `Needs improvement - A community-specific reason -  This is not about an official Ubuntu flavor.` flag, there is no such comment posted. I think that would be a great addition as it would ease the process of making a comment to warn the author about the fact that the distro isn't supported

Comment: This might be relevant. IIRC, the author of a question will see a warning that their post might be closed as soon as it enters the queue. They don't get any notification about it, however. Unsure if this is still the case and/or if it happens will all close reasons.

Comment: What would the benefit be though? A duplicate needs the comment so the OP can know what the suggested duplicate is. Questions about non-official distributions are not on topic and cannot be made on topic. Once the question is closed, the OP is shown the reason for the closure, so what would the benefit of also adding a comment be?